# number of matches from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

help me, please )
I have 2 dataframes, and I want add to df1 additional column with number of matches in df2 for pattern in "pep" column. help me

```
 df1 <-data.frame("id"=c(1, 2, 3), pep = c("bb", "dr", "ac"))
df2 <- data.frame("name" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), "word" = c("drab", "drabbed", "drabbler", "dracaena", "drachma", "academia"))
```

in result I looked for df1

```
   id  pep     n_matches
1  1  bb         2
2  2  dr         5
3  3  ac         3
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "matches"? Do you mean regex matches? In any column of `df2`, or just the `word` column? If there are multiple matches in the same word, do they both count?

Comment: yes,  just the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **base R** approach

```
df1$n_matches <- sapply(df1$pep, function(x) length(grep(x,df2$word)))
df1
  id pep n_matches
1  1  bb         2
2  2  dr         5
3  3  ac         3
```

For completeness I include an extended example if you want to also match all occurrences within a word using `str_match_all` from library `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

# extended example with multiple matches in a word (row 7)
# df2 <- rbind(df2, c("g","drdrbbbb"))
df2
  name     word
1    a     drab
2    b  drabbed
3    c drabbler
4    d dracaena
5    e  drachma
6    f academia
7    g drdrbbbb

df1$n_matches <- sapply(df1$pep, function(x) 
  length(unlist(str_match_all(df2$word, x))))
df1
  id pep n_matches
1  1  bb         4
2  2  dr         7
3  3  ac         3
```

Answer (score 0):

My `dplyr` solution may look a bit ugly compared to normal `dplyr` operations:

```
df1 %>% mutate(n_matches = purr::map(pep, function(x) sum(grepl(x, df2$word))))
```

or

```
df1 %>% mutate(n_matches = purr::map(pep, function(x) length(grep(x, df2$word))))
```

Both returns:

```
  id pep n_matches
1  1  bb         2
2  2  dr         5
3  3  ac         3
```

Explain:

`length(grep("bb", df2$word))` returns the number of matches for `bb` in `df2$word`. However in dplyr, the input to replace `bb` becomes the column vector, so we need the row wise map function `map` to let R know that we apply the function to every row/value in the column vector rather than the column vector directly.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
transform(
  df1, 
  n_matches = as.integer(
    ave(
      df1$pep, 
      df1$pep,
      FUN = function(x){
        length(
          grep(
            x, 
            df2$word
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
```